Why isn't the 0 on my keypad being recognised?
I was trying to finish my project using an physical OUSB-IO board on a ATmega32A board using Microchip Studio's C to create a stopwatch and timer on the same LED board to indicate that it's working. Every detail works from switching a timer to stopwatch and back, setting the timer up (besides 0 which is the major issue due to the fact I can't make it seconds and only minutes) and having a reset/stop button to stop the whole program.
Could anyone help me understand or show me why my 0 doesn't work on the keypad when every button works?
#define F_CPU 1000000UL  // 1 MHz clock speed
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// Define keypad and LED ports
#define KEYPAD_PORT PORTC
#define KEYPAD_DDR  DDRC
#define KEYPAD_PIN  PINC
#define LED_PORT PORTB
#define LED_DDR  DDRB

// Stopwatch/Timer variables
uint8_t mode = 0;  // 0 = stopwatch, 1 = timer
uint16_t time_left = 0;  // Time remaining (timer) or elapsed (stopwatch)
uint8_t is_running = 0;  // Running flag for the timer/stopwatch
uint8_t flash_leds = 0;  // Flag to flash LEDs when timer ends
uint8_t digit_count = 0;  // Track input digits
uint8_t input_digits[4];  // Store digits for MM:SS input

// Keypad initialization
void keypad_init() {
    KEYPAD_DDR = 0xF0;  // Upper 4 bits as output, lower 4 bits as input
    KEYPAD_PORT = 0x0F; // Enable pull-up resistors for the lower 4 bits
}

// Scan the keypad and return the key pressed
char keypad_scan() {
    const char keys[4][4] = {
        {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
        {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
        {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
        {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
    };

    for (uint8_t row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        KEYPAD_PORT = ~(1 << (row + 4));  // Ground one row at a time
        _delay_ms(5);  // Debounce delay

        for (uint8_t col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            if (!(KEYPAD_PIN & (1 << col))) {  // Check if the key is pressed
                _delay_ms(20);  // Additional debounce delay
                while (!(KEYPAD_PIN & (1 << col)));  // Wait for key release
                return keys[row][col];  // Return the pressed key
            }
        }
    }
    return 0xFF;  // No key pressed
}

// Initialize LEDs
void led_init() {
    LED_DDR = 0xFF;  // Set all PORTB pins as outputs (for LEDs)
    LED_PORT = 0x00; // Turn off all LEDs initially
}

// Display the time on the LEDs
void display_time(uint16_t time) {
    uint8_t minutes = time / 60;
    uint8_t seconds = time % 60;
    LED_PORT = (minutes << 4) | (seconds & 0x0F);  // Show minutes and seconds
}

// Convert MM:SS format into total seconds
uint16_t convert_mmss_to_seconds() {
    uint8_t minutes = input_digits[0] * 10 + input_digits[1];
    uint8_t seconds = input_digits[2] * 10 + input_digits[3];
    return minutes * 60 + seconds;  // Total time in seconds
}

// Flash all LEDs when the timer hits zero
void flash_all_leds() {
    LED_PORT ^= 0xFF;  // Toggle all LEDs
    _delay_ms(500);  // 500ms delay for flashing
}

// Main function
int main(void) {
    led_init();     // Initialize LEDs
    keypad_init();  // Initialize the keypad

    while (1) {
        char key = keypad_scan();  // Get the key input

        if (key != 0xFF) {  // If a key is pressed
            // Handle only number inputs (including 0) for setting the time
            if ((key >= '0' && key <= '9') && digit_count < 4) {  // Treat '0' as input along with '1-9'
                input_digits[digit_count++] = key - '0';  // Store the digit, including '0'
                display_time(convert_mmss_to_seconds());  // Show entered time
            }

            // Switch between Timer and Stopwatch modes
            if (key == '*') {
                mode = !mode;  // Toggle the mode
                LED_PORT = (mode == 1) ? 0x01 : 0x02;  // Indicate mode (Timer: LED 0, Stopwatch: LED 1)
            }

            // Start/Stop the timer or stopwatch
            if (key == 'A') {
                if (!is_running) {
                    if (mode == 1) {
                        time_left = convert_mmss_to_seconds();  // Set time_left for Timer mode
                        digit_count = 0;  // Reset digit count
                    } else {
                        time_left = 0;  // In Stopwatch mode, start from 0
                    }
                }
                is_running = !is_running;  // Toggle running state
            }

            // Stop and reset Timer/Stopwatch
            if (key == 'C') {
                time_left = 0;
                is_running = 0;
                flash_leds = 0;
                LED_PORT = 0x00;  // Turn off all LEDs
                digit_count = 0;  // Reset digit count
            }
        }

        // Timer/Stopwatch logic
        if (is_running) {
            _delay_ms(1000);  // 1-second delay

            if (mode == 1 && time_left > 0) {  // Timer mode: countdown
                time_left--;
            } else if (mode == 0) {  // Stopwatch mode: count up
                time_left++;
            }

            display_time(time_left);  // Update the time on the LEDs

            // Check if timer has reached zero
            if (mode == 1 && time_left == 0 && is_running) {
                flash_leds = 1;  // Start flashing LEDs when timer hits 0
                is_running = 0;  // Stop the timer
            }
        }

        // Flash LEDs when the timer hits zero
        if (flash_leds && mode == 1) {
            flash_all_leds();  // Flash all LEDs when timer hits 0
        }
    }
}

I've tried isolating the 0 button and making it a function like A, * and #, but it doesn't work, I've tried making it a normal key_pad scan with 1-9, but it doesn't work. When i press 0 at first the button doesnt register so i would click on 1-9 to create the timer after i set the timer using 1-9, Button 0 would then only pause the timer and nothing else.

What is the value of key (in main) if you press the 0 button?

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify. -- What do you mean by "does not work?" How did you find out? Did you test your keypad scanning routine in isolation to make sure it works with all keys?

“doesn't work” is not an adequate problem description. State specifically input to the program (key presses) that reproduce the problem and what the observed behavior of the program is and what the behavior desired instead is. Further, take steps to diagnose the problem and report their results, including: Seek the earliest point in the program at which misbehavior occurs. Does keypad_scan return the expected value when 0 is pressed? Does the appropriate element of input_digits get the desired value? Change keys to have '1' for 0 instead of '0'. Does the 0 key then act like 1?

char is  signed type with a range of -128..127 according to avr-gcc ABI. Better use uint8_t (or int8_t together with -1 instead of 0xff). Or something like a custom key_t better still.

Ive tried using the uint8_t but the results are still the same when i press 0 nothing apppears and doesnt change the timer alongside when i actually set the timer down 0 only pauses the timer.
